# React, CSS - Remove White Background at the end of the website in App.css

Tags: css, reactjs

I am relatively new to react and css. I am writing a react app. The code in my App.css is

```
.App {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

I hope that the #f0f0f0 background colour will cover my whole page. However, I can always scroll down the website a bit, and the scrolled down part has a white background.

But if I remove the `height: 100vh` part, the #f0f0f0 background will only cover until the end of the last  closing tag, and the rest white background is still there.

How do I get rid of the white background at the end of my page?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css file:

```
body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0
}
```

This will color the entire background of the page.